# How can I access Laravel session data in a React component?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and React and doing a test project but I find myself stuck in terms of accessing data between the two frameworks.

I would like to render an image element created within a React component into a Laravel blade. The source of the image is recieved from {{Session::get('image')}} after a user has uploaded an image via a form in the Laravel blade.

How can I access {{Session::get('image)}} from within the React component state so that I can render the img tag with a dynamic src based on what the user uploads? Authentication is not neccassary.

More info:

I can access the uploaded image in the Laravel blade using:

```
<img src="images/{{Session::get('image')}}" class="img-fluid">
```

from this form:

```
<form action="{{ route('image.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" class="form-control" hidden>
                    <label for="image" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Image 1</label>
                </div>
</form>
```

But I would rather like to render the uploaded image via a React component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Test extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            img : ""
        };
    }
    render () {
        const img = this.state.img;

        return (
            <div className="img-wrapper">
                <img src={`${img}`} alt="test" className="img-fluid" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

How can I feed the data in {{Session::get('image')}} into the img state in the component above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One way would be to render JS code in your laravel view, which assigns the image value to a JS variable.

In your Blade file (above the script tag which loads your react code):

```
<script>
window.image_src = "images/{{Session::get('image')}}";
</script>
```

In the react code:

```
const img = window.image_src;
```

Other options are loading the image source via ajax, or storing it in an HTML element as a data-attribute.

Comment: Thank you, this got me sorted in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what levi said, you can look here https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html, on how to fetch that data, of which you'd need another route that returns the image string